# Refreshing javascript objects with externally loaded content in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, materialize

When I try to load in a collapsible it doesn't work when it is loaded in via javascript. but it does work when I hardcode it in.

I have the following code

```
var VeilingenZoeken = document.getElementById("VeilingenZoeken");

function getZoekResultaten() {
    // console.log(rubriekenzoeken.value);
    const url = "backend/veilingen/VeilingenZoekresultaat.php?q=" + VeilingenZoeken.value;
    fetch(url)
        .then(
            response => response.text()
        ).then(
        html => document.getElementById("veilingItems").innerHTML = html
    );
}
```

That gets called by this html tag

```
<input class="center" type="text" placeholder="Veilingen zoeken..." name="VeilingenZoeken"
               id="VeilingenZoeken" onkeypress="getZoekResultaten();"> <br>
```

It will load in the following piece of html

```
<div class="col s12">
   <ul class="collapsible">       
      <li>
         <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">gavel </i> Gebruikersnaam: <span class="badge"><i  class="material-icons white">info</i></a></span><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="#">Wave</a></div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

However, the collapsible function doesn't work when it is loaded in this way.
Is there any way to force it to load?

**NOTE:** *I think the title is a bit confusing, but I don't have any idea what else would be a suitable title for this post.*

Comment: i guess you just need to initialize the collapsible after you added the innerHTML. use `$('.collapsible').collapsible();`. This is because you add that HTML after materialize has initialized its css.

Comment: I've tried this and it does not seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually initialize collapsible elements by calling  `M.Collapsible.init()` or `collasible()` when using jQuery

> https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html#intialization
>
> **Initialization**
>
> ```
> document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
>   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
>   var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
> });
>
> // Or with jQuery
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   $('.collapsible').collapsible();
> });
> ```

So just call either after loading your content

```
var container = document.getElementById("veilingItems");
fetch(url)
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(html => {
   container.innerHTML = html;
   M.Collapsible.init(container.querySelector('.collapsible'));
   //or if using jQuery
   $('.collapsible').collapsible();
 });
```

Demo

```js
var html = `<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
        <i class="material-icons">gavel</i> Gebruikersnaam:
        <span class="badge">
          <i class="material-icons white">info</i> 
        </span>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="#">Wave</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">Body</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
        <i class="material-icons">gavel</i> Gebruikersnaam:
        <span class="badge">
          <i class="material-icons white">info</i> 
        </span>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" href="#">Wave</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">Body</div>
    </li>
  </ul>`;
var container = document.getElementById("veilingItems");
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.innerHTML = html;
  var collapse = container.querySelector('.collapsible');
  M.Collapsible.init(collapse);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.js"></script>

<div id="veilingItems"></div>
<button>Load</button>
```

Comment: Well, after trying out some code you've provided I've managed to get it working. Thank you